# handle_asynchronously :xxx results in "No route matches [GET]", after reload in "undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job

After watching the [RailsCast about delayed_job](http://railscasts.com/episodes/171-delayed-job-revised), I wanted to use the handle_asynchronously helper like this:

```
class EmailsController < ApplicationController
  handle_asynchronously :import_from_accounts
end
```

Then when I go to my page and hit reload, I get the following error:

```
Routing Error
No route matches [GET] "/de/emails"
```

Afte reloading it again (without changing anything of the code), I get another error (after reloading this error keeps being displayed):

```
NoMethodError in Emails#index

Showing /Users/josh/Documents/Work/Sientia/iq/app/views/shared/iqlist/init.html.haml where line #7 raised:

undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #7):

4:       %tr
5:         %th.icon
6:           = check_box_tag "iqlist_delete_all", "iqlist_delete_all", false, :id => "iqlist_delete_all"
7:         -fields.each do |field|
8:           -field_name = (field.is_a? String )? field : field[:name]
9:           %th
10:             -sort_name=(field_name.split('.').count()>1)? "#{field_name.split('.')[0].pluralize}.#{field_name.split('.')[1]}" : field_name
```

When I change the argument of `handle_asynchronously` to anything else, the same happens again, first GET error, then undefined-method-error.

I'm not really sure what the 2nd error means, it's not my code. But I find it very strange that the error changes from the 1st to the 2nd reload. What could this be? `delayed_job` worked well so far, so I suspect it's something with the `handle_asynchronously` method...

Any idea what the problem is? Thank you, guys.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to solve the first problem first.  To see what your routes are:

```
rake routes
```

I expect that the second error occurs because the first doesn't return anything.